# Fix async in subscribe - what to do instead?

Tags: typescript, rxjs

We have a some code that looks like this:

```
observable.subscribe(async () => {
    await somePromise();
})
```

We have an observable subscription, and inside the subscription handler we want to do something async. As far as I know this will not be awaited and it looks like a code smell to me.

But what to do instead? We could do this:

```
observable.pipe(tap(() => {    await somePromise(); }))
```

and this will not await the Promise too, but will also cause the same linting error.

Or we could do

```
observable.pipe(map(() => somePromise()))
```

which should await the promise and I think needs to be subscribed to to work. What's the best approach to convert this to RxJS code?

Comment: The second example seems pointless, as you know it doesn't solve either problem (what linter error?) Is there a problem with the third? Either you need to turn a promise into an observable or vice versa.

Comment: Why won't it be awaited? What's your expected result from the first code block and what did you got instead?

Comment: This isn't opinion based question. The only correct way of awaiting a promise in an RxJS chain is by merging it into the chain with operators such as `switchMap()`, `mergeMap()`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you need something like this

```
observable
  .pipe(
    switchMap(() => from(somePromise()))
  ).subscribe(value => doWhatYouWantWithValue(value))
```

Comment: note, you don't need to wrap a promise with `from` within `switchMap` unless you want to add a `.pipe()` to it.

Comment: yes, "from" is redundant here